# Как сделать закругленные уголки у стрелки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, clip-path

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытаюсь создать стрелки меню (так называемые, хлебные крошки), как показано на картинке.
Я просмотрел массу решений для `хлебных крошек`, но ни одно из них не могло сделать закругленные углы контура стрелок, поэтому я решил использовать `clip-path`.

мой код:

```css
.box {
      width: 425px;
      height: 90px;
      background-color: #dfdfdf;
      color: white;
      clip-path: polygon(90% 10%, 100% 50%, 90% 90%, 0% 90%, 10% 50%, 0% 10%);
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Я пробовал использовать методы из этого [топика](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31765345/7394871), но в данном случае, когда мы объединяем два пути для создания границы, создатель закругленных углов SVG не применяется к внутреннему. если мы вложим их, чтобы применить SVG к внутреннему, они не подойдут.

Как сделать закругленные уголки для контура стрелки?

Comment: Кажется тут проще взять картинку (нарисовать тот же SVG) и положить фоном.

Comment: @Alexey Ten согласен что проще на SVG, но на CSS тоже нужен ответ

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, т.е. чистый CSS без смешения технологий?

Comment: @UModeL И чистый CSS и гибрид CSS+SVG приветствуются оба варианта!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, это конечно не точь в точь... но, если поиграть с height в before и after, то +- что-то похожее будет... https://codepen.io/darinka-poznyak/details/NWJEVYL может вам чем-то поможет мой пример

Comment: @darinka poznyak Благодарю. Но действительно нужно поиграться ещё с атрибутами для сходства с образцом в вопросе.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, нужно чётче описать желаемый результат. Например, полупрозрачность фона, градиент обводки. А так-то нашли уже этот вопрос, раз решения оттуда тянут. Да и был уже [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1509954/265406).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К сожалению есть небольшие артефакты.

```css
:root {
  --skew-deg: 30deg;
  --border-width: 5px;
  --border-radius: 10px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  width: 425px;
  height: 90px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.box::after,
.box::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
  border: 4px solid darkblue;
  border: var(--border-width, 4px) solid darkblue;
  border-left-width: calc(4px * 1.154);
  border-left-width: calc(var(--border-width, 4px) * (2 - cos(var(--skew-deg, 30deg))));
  border-right-width: calc(4px * 1.154);
  border-right-width: calc(var(--border-width, 4px) * (2 - cos(var(--skew-deg, 30deg))));
}

.box:after {
  top: -7px;
  top: calc(-.75 * var(--border-width, 4px));
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius, 8px) var(--border-radius, 8px) calc(.4 * var(--border-radius, 8px)) 0;
  transform: skewx(30deg);
  transform: skewx(var(--skew-deg, 30deg));
}

.box:before {
  bottom: -7px;
  bottom: calc(-.75 * var(--border-width, 4px));
  left: 0;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  border-radius: 0 calc(.4 * var(--border-radius, 8px)) var(--border-radius, 8px) var(--border-radius, 8px);
  transform: skewx(calc(-1 * var(--skew-deg, 30deg)));
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

так сойдёт? :3

```css
.y{padding: 1em;}
.x{
  position: relative;
  padding: .2em 1em; /*!!!*/
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.9em; /*!!!*/
  font-size: 27px;/*!!!*/
}

.x:before, .x:after{
content: ' ';
color: red;
position: absolute;
width: 80%;
height: 55%;
background: lightgray;/*!!!*/
border-radius: .25em;/*!!!*/
z-index: -1;
left: .5em;
border: 2px solid blue;
}

.x:before{
transform: skew(30deg);/*!!!*/
top: 0;
border-bottom: none;
}

.x:after{
transform: skew(-30deg);/*!!!*/
top: none;
bottom: 0;
border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='y'>
  <b class='x'>что</b>
  <b class='x'>есть</b>
  <b class='x'>эта</b>
  <b class='x'>стрелка,</b>
  <b class='x'>если</b>
  <b class='x'>не</b>
  <b class='x'>пара</b>
  <b class='x'>кусков</b>
  <b class='x'>skew'анутого</b>
  <b class='x'>фона?</b>
</div>
<hr>
<div class='y'>
  <b class='x'>добро</b>
  <b class='x'>пожаловать</b>
  <b class='x'>куда</b>
  <b class='x'>то</b>
  <b class='x'>там</b>
</div>
```

ну а "хвост" заткнуть можно, например радиальным градиентом в маркере.

Comment: Интересное решение, как в прочем всегда у вас. Но нужно сходство с образцом.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, дык основные расхождения в угле стрелок, размере скругления углов и фоне...) сделай я скругления меньше при тех размерах шрифта скруглений не было бы видно :3 в целом подправил. если радиус с `.25em` до `.2em` смените, вроде получится идеальное вхождение по ним. но да, артефакты на хвосте так и не поборол, увы...

Answer (score 3):

```css
.b1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  height: 45px;
  left: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}

.b2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  height: 45px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 45px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
```

Не точь в точь, но лучше, чем было в комментарии (с зеленым фоном)

или так:

```css
.b1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  height: 45px;
  left: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}

.b2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  height: 45px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 53px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transform: skew(-30deg);
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
```

Comment: артефакт на хвосте стрелки хоть и маленький, но остался. Поэтому только плюс за ответ.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, во втором варианте данного ответа артефакт на хвосте гораздо меньше, чем в первом за счет увеличения top для второго прямоугольника и уменьшения border-radius для обоих прямоугольников, но  как по мне, в первом варианте носик стрелки более выразительный